# Coordinates of ROI in ImageView

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have an instance of a `LineSegmentROI` which is added to my `ImageView`.

The LineSegmentROI is free movable.

Now what I want to know are the coordinates of the `LineSegmentROI`.

When i print `getState()` I get wierd coordinates, also they seem like to be constant although I move the `LineSegmentROI`. Here an example:

```
{'angle': 0.0, 'pos': Point(-49.332761, 22.573753), 'size': Point(1.000000, 1.000000)}
{'angle': 0.0, 'pos': Point(-49.332761, 22.573753), 'size': Point(1.000000, 1.000000)}
{'angle': 0.0, 'pos': Point(-49.332761, 22.573753), 'size': Point(1.000000, 1.000000)}
```

In my opinion it should give me coordinates relative to the image I have set to the ImageView.

Here two examples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCAQp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4LTj.png)

Comment: you want to use `pos()` instead of `getState()`

Comment: Surely when I use pos() instead of getState() the function gives me the Value of the pos key. But my problem is that I do not get an update of this values when I use the left and right handle of the ROI. Only the pos value changes when I drag the whole ROI.
I want the pos indendently how I change the ROI!